# Getting Values from Multiple Classes

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

I am trying to scrape the price from:

```
https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers&amp;snr=1_241_4_action_12
```

I am using:

```
soup.find_all('div',{'class':'col search_price responsive_secondrow'})
```

However, there are discounted prices, which are not present in the above div class, instead they can be found using:

```
soup.find_all('div',{'class':'col search_price discounted responsive_secondrow'})
```

I have scraped the Titles of the games, and want the prices also to be correspondingly in the same row, so how do I accomplish merging both the conditions for scraping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it's parent element instead, which contains both prices.

```py
for i in soup.find_all('div',{'class':"col search_price_discount_combined responsive_secondrow"}):
    print(i.text.replace("\n","").strip())
```

Result:

```
$49.99
$59.99
$999.00
$59.99
$59.99
-2%$89.98$87.98
$19.99
-30%$59.99$41.99
$59.99
-70%$59.99$17.99
-10%$29.99$26.99
-5%$39.99$37.99
-30%$29.99$20.99
$29.99
-10%$16.99$15.29
$19.99
-25%$19.99$14.99
$13.99
$99.99
$14.99
$59.99
$19.99
-50%$9.99$4.99
$59.99
$39.99
$59.99
$59.99
-66%$14.99$5.09
$39.99
$49.99
$39.99
-50%$59.99$29.99
-10%$29.99$26.99
-40%$59.99$35.99
$29.98
-67%$59.99$19.79
-50%$29.99$14.99
-30%$19.99$13.99
$2.99
$2.99
$2.99
$2.99
$2.99
$2.99
$14.99
-30%$59.99$41.99
$44.99
-30%$59.99$41.99
$59.99
$59.99
```